# PHP Date("2013-01-10 00:00:00") doesn't work. Alternative? Solution?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Setup:
Working on an old MySQL database and when I query to get a records date field it comes back to me in this format... "2013-01-10 00:00:00"

Details:

I've written a function to return the: DayName mm-dd-yyyy

It works with input format as "10:30pm April 15 2014"

The Question:

How to get it to work with input format as "2013-01-10 00:00:00"
as this is the value returned from the date field in the record I'm working with.

I've read the other responses here but somehow it hasn't clicked :-(

Thanks for any help.

The Code:

```
function date2day_mdy($date2fix) {
    $date_fixed = date("D m-d-Y",$date2fix);
    return $date_fixed;
}
$d=strtotime("10:30pm April 15 2014"); // works - yes
//$d=strtotime)"2013-01-10 00:00:00"); // works - no
$returned_date = date2day_mdy($d);
echo $returned_date."<br>";
```

Comment: Is the syntax error on the non-working line present in your code or just in this post? The first bracket on the function call is flipped.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is here, date('d-m-Y', strtotime("2013-01-10 00:00:00") correctly returns the date in dmY format. Since date/strtotime does check the current locale, you might want to set that first to make sure it isn't mixing up months and days, although even that should return at least a date.

Comment: Your answer led me to this...

Comment: Your answer led me to this...
 //$fld_0 = date2day_mdy($row[0]); // doesn't work
 $d = strtotime($row[0]);          // works
 $fld_0 = date2day_mdy($d);
Thanks for the help and the nudge :-)
Looks like I don't know how to reply with code correction... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I try this in a online sandbox and it works, but you must change your bracket.

```
function date2day_mdy($date2fix) {
    $date_fixed = date("D m-d-Y",$date2fix);
    return $date_fixed;
}
$d=strtotime("10:30pm April 15 2014"); // works - yes
//$d=strtotime)"2013-01-10 00:00:00"); // works - no
$returned_date = date2day_mdy($d);
echo $returned_date."<br>";
```

The line you comment out should be written in this format:

```
$d=strtotime("2013-01-10 00:00:00");
```

And then I get the following output from the sandbox:

```
Thu 01-10-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried earlier to post this as a comment to an earlier Answer but I couldn't figure out how to do CR LF... so everything came out on one continuous line.

The initial answer got me to take another look and this worked... which was also referenced by a later poster...

```
//where $row[0] containes "2013-01-10 00:00:00"
$d = strtotime($row[0]); 
$fld_0 = date2day_mdy($d);
echo $fld_0;
```

Thanks for the help folks.